# Navigate with page reload using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-router

My application uses a Laravel backend and a React frontend. Ordinarily, I would use e.preventDefault() so that there are no page reloads. The issue I am having is that if I login or logout without a page refresh, it causes a CSRF mismatch on future requests. So I'm okay with the page refresh. However, when I remove e.preventDefault(), the form data becomes appended to the URL. The best solution I have been able to come up with is this:

```
  let csrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
      axios.post('login', {email, password}, {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
      })
      .then(() => {
        setLoginStatus(true)
        navigate('/')
        window.location.reload();
      })
  }
```

This essentially works, but I don't like it. What happens is that the view is updated with the Component at '/,' and then the page refreshes. It just looks weird. All I want is for the Component at '/' to be rendered upon the form's submission with a page reload. Keeping in mind my problem with removing e.preventDefault(), where the form data gets added to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't realize this problem. But I think you can use useEffect and useState together.

For example: When the login operation finishes, set the data which will be gained to state. And make dependency with useEffect and that state. So if the state change the component automaticaly re-render beacuse of the useEffect. In this case no reload needed.